# SumProduct with 2 criterias including wildcard

Tags: excel, sum, criteria, excel-2013

I have `SumProduct` working but it does not seem to be capturing all the values.

Here is a sample data:

[image]

I would like to match `WiFi Services*`, `Day` and then sum up the values in Column I.

This is my formula that does not seem to be capturing call the correct minutes.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(Table164[Call Description],13)="WiFi Services")*(Table164[Time Rate]=AA20)*(Table164[Mins]))
```

Cell `AA20` is referring to the Time Rate: `Day`

Does anyone have an idea why the above formula is not capturing everything or they have a better approach to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you implement the wild card in the formula? (`"WiFi Services*"`)

> =SUMIFS(I:I,G:G,"WiFi Services*", H:H, "Day")

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this works? I thought SumProduct() function does not support an array-type expression?

Comment: Your edit now only looks at 1 criteria instead of 2 right? Maybe I did not explain correctly in the above - but I would like to capture 2 criterias and then sum up the minutes

Comment: Sorry so sloppy, was rushing before leaving work. Tested and working above :)

Comment: Perfect - that works great! Is it possible to have 2 or more criterias within 1 criteria range? E.g. If there was my records and I wanted to sum up WiFi Services* and Fixed Rate* in column G?

Comment: If I follow, you would just use the current equation and then tack on another SUMIF(S). **SUMIFS(these criteria’s) + SUMIFS(these criteria’s)**

Comment: It's not in my example but I was thinking going forward. Yes - that works but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it really